# xterm creates window in active workspace always (How to put the window into background)

Tags: workspaces, xterm

I have two workspaces: WS1 and WS2.

On WS1, the script below is running in a konsole:

```
for i in 1..1000; do

    xterm -e someprogram argX &;
    xterm -e someprogram argY
; done
```

When I switch to WS2, these xterms starts to show up in WS2. Wherever I am,  new windows always pop up on the active workspace. It distract a lot. How can I manage this? I dont want to remove `xterm -e`, because once in a while I want to compare outputs of the two commands.

Comment: If anything, your window manager is the one that is responsible to take care of this. Which window manager or desktop environment are you using? Then, it may be the case that some window managers can't really track `xterm`: the one I use, `i3wm`, (by default?) only offers that support for applications that have the "startup notification", effectively creating any other new window in the workspace you are when it is created.

Comment: I use gnome classic. how can I find out if I use i3wm or not? xterm has an option called `-maximized`, if it had a `-minimized` option it would do it.

Comment: GNOME by default uses the gnome's own window manager. So, unless you explicitly tried to change the wm, you're using GNOME's own wm. Sure, a `-minimized` would prevent it from starting opened, but it would still start on the current desktop; if what bugs you is the window appearing in top of what you are doing and you just want to background it, I'd suggest changing the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found it.

Solution is to add `-iconic`

Example:`xterm -iconic -e someprogram ArgX`